# Ambiguous varargs methods with Object and primitive type

Tags: java, variadic-functions, primitive-types

Consider the following two sets of methods.  The first one is accepted, the second one is rejected as ambiguous. The only difference is between using int and Integer.

Is there a particular need to reject the second one?  That would imply that accepting it after boxing (which would lead to the first set) has a problem. What do I miss here?

From my point of view, the Java compiler is too restrictve here.

Set 1:

```
public void test(Object... values) {}

public void test(Integer x, Object... values) {} // difference here

public void b() {
    test(1, "y"); // accepted
}
```

Set 2:

```
public void test(Object... values) {}

public void test(int x, Object... values) {} // difference here

public void b() {
    test(1, "y"); // marked as ambiguous
}
```

Set 2 produces the compiler error:

```
 error: reference to test is ambiguous
    test(1, "y"); // marked as ambiguous
    ^
  both method test(Object...) in T and method test(int,Object...) in T match
```

Java 1.8, Eclipse Oxygen

Comment: The methos from Set 1 and Set 2 are in the same class?

Comment: @RafaelVieiraCoelho Of course not.

Comment: same class. I just edit the class to change between the two.

Comment: @UlrichScholz can you show where/how it is rejected? Ie. the use case?

Comment: @pedromss Everything necessary is in the question already. @Ulrich What happens if you try to compile with `javac`?

Comment: @pedromss. I'm not fully getting your question. The use case is that we have/had code in our code base that provoked the problem. The example code I give is minimal example. Eclipse shows the problem as compilation error. javac fails with compilation error.

Comment: @UlrichScholz you should have put in the actual error. Just added it for you. Generally, make your [MCVE] compile and include full error output.

Comment: Well, at least it's not a discrepancy between `javac` and Eclipse's compiler. Someone will probably dig up the relevant part of JLS soon...

Answer (score 5):

What the compiler doing is implementing the rules set out in [JLS 15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5) for choosing the most specific method in the cases where multiple methods are applicable for the invocation.  In the examples in your question, the difference is covered by this line in the spec:

> A type `S` is more specific than a type `T` for any expression if `S <: T` (§4.10).

where `S <: T` means that `S` is a subtype of `T`.

In example #1:

- There are two applicable methods
- The type `Integer` is a subtype of `Object`, so it is more specific.
- Therefore the second method is more specific than the first.
- Therefore the second method is chosen.

In example #2:

- There are two applicable methods
- The type `int` is not a subtype of `Object` or vice versa, so neither type is more specific than the other.
- Therefore the neither method is more specific than the other.
- Therefore the invocation is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that in the first case, the `1` argument needs to be boxed into Integer, and then the most fitting method chosen; that being the `(Integer, Object...)` version.

In the second case, there are two options - boxing or not. This is what makes it ambiguous.

I agree that this is counter-intuitive.

Comment: I agree, the compiler correctly implements the specification. My point is that the Java compiler could easily lift this restriction at compile time: no need for complex analysis. The specification is just too restrictive

Answer (score 0):

To close this issue, let me summarize actual answers to my question as I understand them: the behaviour is correct according to the specification.  The specification could be relaxed such that primitive types are covered as their non-primitive counterparts.  One reason that's not done yet is the complexity of specifying and implementing a fast and correct parser.